# How to place header and ui file in different folders using autouic in cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#autouic), regarding autouic:

> If a preprocessor #include directive is found which matches ui_.h, and a .ui file exists, then uic will be executed to generate the appropriate file.

But what if the .ui file is in another folder? I currently get the following error when trying to build:

```
AUTOUIC : error : process for ui_module.h failed:
File 'C:/app/source/headers/module.ui' is not valid
```

The ui file is actually located here:

```
C:/app/source/forms/module.ui
```

I've tried to add the `C:/app/source/forms/` to the `include_directories()`-macro without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15227) mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661285/1597714) is now resolved.

This worked in **CMake v3.9.0-rc6**:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS your/folder/here)
```

See documentation of [AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS.html).

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

A search path, CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS, has been added to CMake 
version 3.9.

---

After further investigation, it seems like it's not possible to do. There is an open issue in their tracking system, but it is so far not implemented:

[Add Search path for AUTOUIC](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15227)