# CMake Qt UIC failed

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake, uic

I'm currently porting my project from qmake to CMake and I'm facing a problem with Qt UIC which tries to process a UI file that does not exist instead of the actual file I want it to process.

I have the following file hierarchy:

```
.
|___ CMakeLists.txt
|___ MyProject.pro
|___ mainwindow.ui
|___ resource.qrc
|___ source
|    |___ mainwindow.cpp
|    |___ *.cpp
|___ include
|    |___ mainwindow.h
|    |___ *.h
```

And here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

# Project name
project(project)

# Tell CMake to compile with C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Tell CMake to run moc when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Tell CMake to run uic when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# Tell CMake to run rcc when needed
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

# Moc generated files are located in the current dir so we need to tell CMake to look for them.
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Find Qt5
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui OpenGL REQUIRED)
# Add Qt5 definitions and includes to build libraries. 
# Widgets add Widgets Core and Gui
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES})

add_definitions(${Qt5OpenGL_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories(${Qt5OpenGL_INCLUDES})


# Find OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# Set include directories
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    
# Use Qt5 ressources
set(RESOURCE resources.qrc)
# Use Qt5 ui
set(UI mainwindow.ui)

# Adding sources
set(SOURCES
    source/main.cpp
    source/mainwindow.cpp
    source/octree.cpp
    source/mesh.cpp
    source/pgm3d.cpp
    source/glwidget.cpp
    source/camera.cpp
    source/scene.cpp 
    source/light.cpp 
    source/obj.cpp 
    source/alignedbox3f.cpp 
    source/wireboundingbox.cpp

    include/mainwindow.h
    include/utils.h
    include/octree.h
    include/mesh.h
    include/pgm3d.h
    include/glwidget.h
    include/camera.h
    include/scene.h
    include/model3d.h
    include/light.h
    include/obj.h
    include/alignedbox3f.h
    include/wireboundingbox.h)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${UI} ${RESOURCE} ${SOURCES} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5OpenGL_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

And I've got the following error:

```
File '/*/project/source/mainwindow.ui' is not valid
AUTOUIC: error: process for ui_mainwindow.h needed by
 "/*/project/source/mainwindow.cpp"
failed:
File '/*/project/source/mainwindow.ui' is not valid
```

This error is perfectly logical since my source folder does not contain the UI file. I've tried to wrap the UI instead of using `AUTOUIC` and it didn't work either.

Comment: Try to clean the build directory cache and start again. Also I would recommend not to put in the project dir the object files. Keep it clean.

Comment: Already tried to clean everything up but It didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`AUTOUIC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html) property of the target (which is set from the variable `CMAKE_AUTOUIC` when the target is created) defines behavior of generator - when `AUTOUIC` property is enabled CMake will **scan** source files for the includes of ui files (like `#include "ui_*.h"` or `#include <ui_*.h>`) and will **automatically** process them with `uic` tool.
In CMake 3.9 another target property was added [`AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS.html). Similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661285/3344612).

---

Another option for you would be to disable `AUTOUIC` and use [`qt5_wrap_ui`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/cmake-manual.html) with full path to the UI file:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC OFF)
set(UI ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mainwindow.ui)
...
qt5_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS ${UI})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${UI_HEADERS} ${RESOURCE} ${SOURCES} )
```