# How to generate ui source files from a list of ui files

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I'm porting a legacy C++ + Qt project to CMake and as a first step I do not want to touch the original project tree, so that the CMake project can be a drop-in patch that just extends the original project.

However, the original project tree stores UI files in a dedicated folder that's separated from all the source and header files.

I've tried setting `CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS` to point to the UI folder, as mentioned in [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630820/how-to-place-header-and-ui-file-in-different-folders-using-autouic-in-cmake/45132079#45132079), and also pass the list of UI files to `qt_wrap_ui`.  However, none of these tricks had any effect, and I never manage to get the CMake project to generate the ui_ source files.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get cmake to reliably generate source files from Qt's ui stashed in any arbitrary folder within the project tree?

Comment: a [mre] of what you've tried would be helpful

Comment: qt_wrap_ui() will work, no matter where the ui files are.

Comment: We had all `ui_*.h` files in "${sourceDir}/tmp/" and `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` seems to be working fine. Just make sure that the headers are included correctly. We had many cpp files that include ui headers like so: `#include ".\tmp\ui_MyWindow.h"`. CMake is not able to recognize them as ui headers, so you need to correct them (`"tmp/ui_MyWindow.h"`). Also make sure that actual *.ui files live close to cpp using them.